# How do I read an escaped unicode character from an XML file into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, unicode

I have an XML attribute which contains a Unicode character which I need to read into JavaScript and act upon, and I'm having a hard time understanding how escaping works. My XML file might contain:

```
<item foo="\u265c" />
```

I bring the XML file using XMLHttpRequest, but I have the following result:

```
x = itemObject.getAttribute('foo') // x = "\\u265c"
y = decodeURIComponent(x)          // y = "\\u265c"
```

What am I missing here? I want `y` to be the decoded Unicode character. I could create a function which catches and interprets the `\\u` string and converts it, but I'm assuming there's a more elegant way to handle it.

Should I have it stored in the XML file differently, or should I be doing something different on the JavaScript side of things? Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `u265c` unicode character in XML or HTML will be expressed like that: `&#x265c;`
.
see it working [here](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=e2ce4b7e-e0f6-484c-82d6-89bf7c0db036).

You can also write a conversion function:
[working example](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=026a3e3e-b37b-4915-a806-22054b24dc9e)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="convert" onClick="convert('u265c')"/>
    <span id="myspan"></span>


    <script>
    function convert(unchar)
      {
        var base = '&#x';
        var fixed = unchar.replace("u","");
        document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = base + fixed + ";";
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple. In my case, I'm designing the XML file as well, so it's no problem to encode it the right way using `&#x`. I was putting it in the XML file in JS format, without realizing that XMLHttpRequest would automatically handle the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The convention `\u265c` means nothing to XML or to any XML-processing software. (The native XML representation would be `&#x265c;`).

If you've got a document where, for some reason, the author has decided to represent the character as `\u265c` rather than `&#x265c;`, then you'll have to find some way of decoding it at application level. In XPath 2.0 it's not too difficult to write a simple function that converts hex to decimal, and then you can use the `codepoints-to-string()` function to convert the decimal number to a Unicode character.